# How to Update UIScrollView when an index of array is Deleted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am new to IPhone Development. can some one tell me how to update the content of UIScrollview. i have an NSMutable Array that contains different quotes so if i delete one of the quotes from the scrollview how it can be remove from view and page should move to the next page if the middle one is deleted and should go to the previous one if the last index of an array is deleted. Please Help!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please be specific of what your technical issues actually is. Providing your code would really make it easier for the community to fill out of what is missing.

Comment: The goal of this site is for us to help you with your solution, not to give you a solution. It's a small but important difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after deleting image remove that data from array
[dataarray removeObjectAtIndex:selectedindex];
now again call the scrollview method

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to create two methods - for adding and removing objects from the `NSMutableArray` and inside them change the contents of the `UIScrollView`. For example:

```
-(void)addObjectToArray:(id)obj
{
    [self.myArray addObject:obj];
    //Create and initialize a view with a quote for example and add it in the UIScrollView
    [self.scrollView addSubView:someView];
}

-(void)removeObjectFromArray:(id)obj
{
    [self.myArray removeObject:obj];
    //Find the view you need to remove, either by tag or your array is actually from views,
    //and remove it from the UIScrollView
    [someView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Then when inserting or deleting objects from the array use those methods

```
[self addObjectToArray:someObject];
[self removeObjectFromArray:someObject];
```

There are some other more elegant approaches using KVO, but need to read some info about that..